# Form transitions in VB.NET without using Timers

Tags: vb.net, winforms, transition

For couple of hobby projects of mine, I've been performing form transitions (fade-in/out, slide-left/right) using timer control, and I know its not the right way to do it. Using timer has its own disadvantages as it is a CPU hog if logic is complex and also, transitions are not smooth. So, I'm wondering how can I perform form transitions without using any timers and just by using native Windows API or any third-party library. I came across with FlowFX but found that it is limited only to .NET Compact framework.

Thanks...

Comment: Must you use winforms?  WPF makes those sorts of things easier, although it has a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: Chris Dunaway: Planning to move to WPF but the current app I'm working on is small such that using WPF in there might make it bloated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know what your timer handler is doing without a code sample, but using a timer to do animations is an acceptable method.

[Here is another SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188349/simple-animation-using-c-windows-forms) that might show you a better way of coding your timer handler.

The "not smooth" part could perhaps be overcome using double-buffering.

Comment: I thought GDI+ has animation capabilities but I haven't explored it well. Anyways thanks for that "double-buffer" hint, was totally unaware of that, I'm a newbie in .NET :-)