# How to create a smooth animation using C# Windows forms?

Tags: c#, forms, animation, smoothing

due my school project I must create a game using Windows forms only..

I have decided to create a 2D racing game. So now I need to move the car image.
To move it I tried to animate the car with the KeyDown event, however the animation is really Faltering.. 
So is there any other way to create animation? or is it possible to soomth it somehow?
(For the car I use a PictureBox that Docked to the form and in its paint event im redrawing the car in the right window positions.)

Comment: I suggest you read up on double buffering.

Comment: Quite a big topic. This thread might provide some pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188349/simple-animation-using-c-windows-forms

Comment: Post what you have done so far.

Comment: Have you thought about WPF? WinForms is just not the best Fx for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This post should solve your issues:
[simple-animation-using-c-windows-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188349/simple-animation-using-c-windows-forms)

He details how he went around coding animation in a windows form and covers some of your questions.

If that doesn't solve it, look up using some XNA libraries as Freeman said.

Answer (score 2):

From the details you provided, i can say this, if you wish to create a mini-game i would recommend you use WPF with some XNA libraries, because WinForms is not really cut out to enable a very impresive graphic experience, but rather it favours the creation simple GUI tools. Sometimes not even double buffering helps much.

Comment: some XNA libraries can also be used with windows forms in that case, and these libraries are especially designed to optimize the rendering of graphics for managed runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

well you can make a movement-animation system

```
        int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
        int y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) x += 1;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x -= 1;
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);
```

to make it faster change the x+=1 x-=1 and y+=1 y-=1; to bigger numbers like y x-=3;
so in this cod you yous the arrow keys but only the right and left because you will be driving foward reapeatedly so you only move right and left