# loop update inside windowsForms

Tags: c#

I want to create an animation moving object .. in order to move this object i need to update the coordinates x and y or one of them, the problem is the object is jamb to the final position with no smooth moving animation as suppose to... I used thread sleep but doesn't just make the code freeze then the object jamb.. Here is the not working part of the code

```
public void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (flag)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i = i + 1)
        {
            x-position = x-position + 3;
            Invalidate();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);//instead of stop for 5 second and continue the loop is stop 5 second and go to i=100 the final value in the loop
        }
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: From what you are saying it sounds like your nnew value is coming in as 99 so the integrator is going to 100 next.

Comment: Thank you for response, nnew is equal to 0

Comment: Please provide more code as  there is not enough information to go by. What event is t_Tick set to? When and how is flag set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Refresh()` instead of `Invalidate()` to force drawing the control immediately. By calling `Invalidate()`, you essentially just tell the control that some of its parts (or everything) needs to be repainted, but not to do it right now. Please note that this is not a good way of doing it, as calling `Thread.Sleep` causes your UI thread to be blocked.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188349/simple-animation-using-c-windows-forms) for a similar question and its answers where a more canonical way is used.

Comment: Thank you so much It's work fine when I use Refresh()  instead of Invalidate ()...

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself the question:

> What do I want my code to do once every `t.Interval` millisecond?

The answer is

> Move the `Control` once.

So move it only once in the `t_Tick` method.

You think my answer is wrong because there is no `for` loop, but there is one included in the timer. In the `Timer` class, there is some code that does domsething like this:

```
while (true) {
  form1.t_Tick(...);
  Thread.Sleep(Interval);
}
```

**NOTE:** this is not real code found in the `Timer` code, it's just meant to explain the concept behind timers.

### So what does your current code do?

It moves exactly how you would like it to do, but `Thread.Sleep()` blocks the thread you are on and nothing else is done, just like if you had a debug breakpoint on that line of code. Therefore, `Invalidate()` may be called, but the code that repaints your form isn't called until you leave the `for` loop (when it has moved completely).