# Animation in .gif is not showing in windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, desktop-application, picturebox

I am very new to c# and windows form.

What I am trying is to add a PictureBox to a windows form and display an animated .gif image before I display the data in the form.

Here is the code for the PictureBox :

```
private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;

            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this.pictureBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.AppWorkspace;
            this.pictureBox1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox1.Image")));
            this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(374, 442);
            this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(16, 16);
            this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 19;
            this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
            this.pictureBox1.Visible = false;
```

Now, on a button click the gif image should be loaded in the picture box . The code for that goes like this :

```
private void scanButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
            pictureBox1.Refresh();  
        }
```

Now, when I click the button "Scan Button", the image becomes visible,but the animation is not working.

Please can anyone help me what is happening here ?

Thanks!

Comment: For your .gif animation to work, your main (UI) thread should be free. If you are performing any process on main thread then you will not get animation effect.

Comment: You may find this post useful: [Show Transparent Loading Spinner above other Controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220327/show-transparent-loading-spinner-above-other-controls)

Answer (score 4):

For your .gif animation to work, your **main (UI) thread should be free.** If you are performing any process on main thread then you will not get animation effect.

From your question, it seems like you are performing Scanning operation on click of button. That may be the problem.

To get rid of this problem, you will have to make sure that your main thread is free and any operation (like Scanning) should be on separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the path to the image in `ImageLocation`.

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "C:\\throbber.gif";
```

The `PictureBox` will understand that it's an animated image and play it. Disabling the `PictureBox` or the `Form` will stop the animation from playing.

Answer (score -2):

If you really need to use picture box you can iterate over a collection of images. But i strongly recommend using WebBrowser (mind it is basically IE)

This should help you with all animations using windows forms
[Simple animation using C#/Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188349/simple-animation-using-c-windows-forms[1])