# Draw loading circle on windows form

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, windows-forms-designer

How can I draw a loading circle(animated) on windows forms? Is it possible to make it big and transparent, so that underlying text on form is still visible.

Displaying a gif is not a kind of solution i'm looking for.

Thx.

Comment: Please let me know if there is solution to 2nd part of question, "how can we make sure of consistency if form is full of grid or button or textbox?" something like, draw this one layer above current form, so that everything underlying is visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you can do this using [Graphics.DrawEllipse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawellipse(v=VS.80).aspx) (for one or multiple circles, depending on the exact UI effect you're trying to achieve), using a pen with a non-opaque alpha value.

Comment: I didn't understand how do we draw animated loading circle with this function call.
example of loading circle:
http://www.google.com/search?q=loading+circle&hl=en&rlz=1C1GPCK_enIN400&prmd=ivns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=pnTvTdn5CITtrQfJzs3NBQ&ved=0CCMQsAQ&biw=1280&bih=675

Comment: Graphics.DrawEllipse is the primitive for drawing a single circle, and you can adjust the transparency using the alpha value.  You can draw a "ring" of these each update (using basic circle-drawing logic, e.g. iterating over 2*pi radians by steps, and using cos(t)*radius,sin(t)*radius to find ellipse centers).  To animate, you'll need to do this periodically, either during a progress-callback or a timer.  Here's some more info on that step: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318/simple-animation-in-winforms

Comment: Here's the MSDN page on alpha blending (opacity) in GDI+ - as you can see by the images, you can make graphic elements seem to "fade out" by using this feature: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533803(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Also - here's an article on CodeProject on "How to write a loading circle animation in .NET": http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mrg_loadingcircle.aspx

Comment: More over, if there is a button on form, i can see breaks at that place. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: If you want the circle to overlay the entire control you can render it to an otherwise transparent bitmap, and just overlay it on top of your control.