# How to change form with animation?

Tags: c#, winforms, animation

How to change form with animation(like fading,Cutl Up,...) in win application?

I have two form Form1,Form2.
I'm in form1 and there is a button on it and i want to change form when button clicked.

```
//button click
Form2 f2=new Form2();
this.hide();
f2.show();
```

Comment: Now what is your exception here? Is it not working fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`AnimateWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), define a new form class and override `OnLoad()` to show the form with your desired effects.

```
// Console Application
// Load System.Windows.Forms reference.

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool AnimateWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int dwTime, int dwFlags);

class SlidingForm: System.Windows.Forms.Form 
{
    const int AW_ACTIVATE = 0X20000;
    const int AW_SLIDE = 0X40000;
    const int AW_HOR_POSITIVE = 0X1;

    protected override void OnLoad(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        AnimateWindow(this.Handle, 1000, AW_ACTIVATE | AW_SLIDE | AW_HOR_POSITIVE);
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var frm = new SlidingForm().ShowDialog;
}
```

---

Sample code to hide a PictureBox control as requested:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   const int AW_HIDE = 0x00010000;
   const int AW_SLIDE = 0x00040000;
   const int AW_HOR_NEGATIVE = 0x00000002;
   const int AW_HOR_POSITIVE = 0x00000001;
   // Toggle show/hide
   AnimateWindow(pictureBox1.Handle, 1000, (pictureBox1.Visible) ? (AW_HIDE | AW_HOR_NEGATIVE) : (AW_HOR_POSITIVE) | AW_SLIDE);
   pictureBox1.Visible ^= true;
}
```

Comment: thank you. is it possible to use it for controls like picturebox?

Comment: Yes, it's generally possible to pass the handle of a control like a `PictureBox` to `AnimateWindow` function. For example: `AnimateWindow(PictureBox1.Handle, 1000, AW_VER_NEGATIVE | AW_SLIDE | AW_HIDE);` will hide the `PictureBox` control with vertical slide effect.

Comment: I use this code but doesn't work : AnimateWindow(pictureBox1.Handle, 5000, AW_ACTIVATE | AW_BLEND | AW_HOR_POSITIVE);

Comment: AnimateWindow returns a bool, not an int.  Use it to throw a Win32Exception so the OP knows he's using it wrong.  Can't activate a child window.

Comment: @HansPassant while `BOOL` type is mapped to int, is there any downsides using int here?

Comment: Meh, bool is the natural mapping.  There's a huge downside in not using it.

Comment: @fardjad can you explain what should i do for : i want to animate a picturebox(for example hide it) when user clicked button1

Comment: @iCoder The problem with your code is you're using `AW_BLEND` on a non-top level window. Also `AW_ACTIVATE` is not needed for showing a child window. I updated the answer and added a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into the specifics of the code itself, I found this question which handles a similar subject: [Simple animation in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318/simple-animation-in-winforms).

That question leads me to a library called [dot-net-transitions](http://code.google.com/p/dot-net-transitions/) which I think does exactly what you want.

Comment: For example i use this code for background color but nothing happen : Transition.run(this, "BackColor", Color.Red, new TransitionType_Linear(1000));