# Creating shapes that can change their shape and location dynamically using C# and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dynamic, draw, shapes

How can I create interactive shapes that can change their shape and location (with time or based on some event) on the screen using C# and Visual Studio ?

Which type of application to choose? Which type of objects to choose where I can draw such objects?

I am a rookie...

Answer (score 0):

You can start from a WPF application.
in this application you can Use the System.Windows.Controls.Canvas control.
this control can has a collection of other controls (the shapes that you will use)
this control let you specify the location of your shapes using two attached Property "Left" and "Top"
here is an exmple.

```
Canvas.SetLeft(shape1, 10);
Canvas.SetTop(shape2, 20);
```

and you can change the "Width" and the "Height" properties of the Shape.

all of this can be done in the event handlers , which responding to the events in your application.

if you have more questions, I am ready.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the easiest way would be by using WinForms.

Try to look here:
[Simple animation in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318/simple-animation-in-winforms)

you can genenerally animate any visual object just by changing its display properties( position, size...) and then forcing a redraw. WinForms are event-driven and the individual OnPaint handlers are called when the form is invalidated.