# Cannot show Ripple Effect when click the control

Tags: c#, infinite-loop

I'm trying to show my Ripple Effect when the control is clicked but it doesn't work. I think it was some kind of infinite loop but I can't find the bugs. Here's my code in OnMouseClick:

```
    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
        xx = MousePosition.X;
        yy = MousePosition.Y;
        allow = true;
        while (allow)
        {
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

and this is my code in OnPaint:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        var G = e.Graphics;
        G.DrawString(Text, Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), R, SF);
        if (SizeAnimation > 190) allow = false;
        if (allow)
        {
            SizeAnimation = SizeAnimation + 25;
            G.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(198, 180, 232)), xx, yy, SizeAnimation, SizeAnimation);
            G.DrawString(Text, Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), R, SF);
        }
    }
```

The size of the control is 145 and 45.
Can anyone explain the bugs to me and fix it? Thank you very much :D

Comment: `OnPaint` can't run till `OnMouseClick` returns. You can't put your while loop there. You will need to rework your logic. There are better ways [to do animations in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318/simple-animation-in-winforms) and doing it in WPF is super easy and built in.

Comment: thanks, I'll try :D