# Is there another way to use Graphics.DrawImage()?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have my paint method drawing images using the `e.Graphics.DrawImage(myImage);`
e is the paint event args. I want to show an animation if a bool is true, otherwise I want to draw some other images.

In the paint event method, I have code similar to this:

```
if(myBool) 
{
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(nextFrame);
}
else
{
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(backgroundImage);
}
```

`backgroundImage` is a picture for my background, not just one plain color that I could replace with the actual `Form1` background attribute. `nextFrame`is an image that is set to the next frame of the animation I want to play by a timer.
When I run my program, there is significant lag and I think it's because I'm constantly using an if statement whenever the paint method is called.

If there was a way to use `e.Graphics.DrawImage();` in another method, then I would use it then so that there are less if statements. Or is there a way to simplify my paint method to be less laggy.

Note:
The animation and background images cover the entire screen, which have a resolution of 2256x1504, meaning those also might be causing the lag, in which case I would need to find a way to improve the speed of `e.Graphics.DrawImage();`

Comment: Your post lacks crucial info: Where do you draw and when? For an animation you need a Timer to trigger the Paint event by Invalidating the control or Form in its Tick, The target should be double-buffered..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple animation in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318/simple-animation-in-winforms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is whether there's another way to use `Graphics.DrawImage` in order to draw the entire screen quickly enough to serve as an animation.

One "other way" would be to invoke it indirectly by detecting changes to the `myBool` property and modifying the `BackgroundImage` property of the main form in response to that. If `myBool` is true, the animation consists of iterating the array of background images.

When I tested this approach it seemed pretty zippy, but you may have to actually [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/alt-graphics-scheme.git) my sample to see whether it's fast enough for your application.

[image: animation]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DoubleBuffered = true; // Smoother if true but compare performance with/without.
        var dir = 
            Path.Combine(
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                "Backgrounds");

        _backgrounds =
            Directory
            .GetFiles(dir)
            .Select(_ => (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(_))
            .ToArray();
        BackgroundImage = _backgrounds[0];
        checkBoxMyBool.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) => myBool = checkBoxMyBool.Checked;
    }
    private readonly Bitmap[] _backgrounds;

    public bool myBool
    {
        get => _myBool;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_myBool, value))
            {
                _myBool = value;
                _ = onMyBoolChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    bool _myBool = false;
    private async Task onMyBoolChanged()
    {
        if(myBool)
        {                
            for (int i = 1; i < _backgrounds.Length; i++)
            {
                BackgroundImage = _backgrounds[i];
                await Task.Delay(100);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            BackgroundImage = _backgrounds[0];
        }
    }
}
```